# getting error updating the sqlite

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, ios8

I am doing the project and I am structed in database path. I am using the sqlite database for storing. In this my problems is when I updating the table it showing the error. For database part I am using prewritten classes. I am calling that class method whenever I need. See below you can understand.

This below code is working fine

```
[DataCachingHelper updateTable:@"sendertable" data:dic3 where:@"MESSAGE_ID='1234'"];
```

but when I am sending the object to the "where", It showing some error.

```
[DataCachingHelper updateTable:@"sendertable" data:dic3 where:@"MESSAGE_ID=%@",@"hai"];
```

i am getting the error:

```
"too many arguments to methods call expected 3,have 4".
```

here `MESSAGE_ID` is `VARCHAR TYPE`

Comment: What is the data type of `MESSAGE_ID` ? and what error it gives when you send `@"MESSAGE_ID='1234'`?

Comment: @Virussmca MESSAGE_ID is the varchartype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is clear here. You can not pass string format because compiler compiles parameter before converting into string format. From your method declaration allowed parameters must be 3.

So compiler detect 4 parameter as you pass string with format.

Also in `sqlite` database for `VARCHAR` type field use double quotes for field values.

So your string should be like this:

```
NSString *whereClauseString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MESSAGE_ID = \"%@\"",@"hai"];
```

Or if value is pre known simply create string like this:

```
NSString *whereClauseString = @"MESSAGE_ID = \"hai\"";
```

And then use this string as third parameter for `updateTable` method:

```
[DataCachingHelper updateTable:@"sendertable" data:dic3 where:whereClauseString];
```

Answer (score 0):

make this in two step.

```
   NSString *strWhere=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"MESSAGE_ID='%@'",@"hai"];

   [DataCachingHelper updateTable:@"sendertable" data:dic3 where:strWhere];
```

Comment: i tried with single quotes also but i am getting the same error

Comment: what is type of MESSAGE_ID in database, int or string

Comment: MESSAGE_ID ID IS THE VARCHAR TYPE

Comment: try , just modified answer